# Laravel 5 checkif Admin middleware logic not correct (one to many with role)

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, eloquent, admin

I'm building a Laravel 5 REST-webapp. Now I would like to add an Admi. I have done so by setting an one-to-many relation (user can have 1 role, 1 role can have many users) table
Like so:

```
public function role()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Role::class);
}
```

This works, I have a user with an role_id.
But now I'm stuck writing the middleware and using this role_id correctly.

Now, my admin middleware is

```
public function handle($request,  Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::User()->isRole('Admin')) {
        return $next($request);
    }
    return redirect()->guest('login');
}
```

And in my User Model I have:

```
public function isRole($roleName)
{

    if ($this->with('role') == $roleName)
    {
        print_r($this->with('role.name'));
    }

    return false;
}
```

But this code just sends me to the home page.

My Middleware Logic is wrong (everything else is setup correctly).

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably change:

```
public function isRole($roleName)
{

    if ($this->with('role') == $roleName)
    {
        print_r($this->with('role.name'));
    }

    return false;
}
```

into:

```
public function isRole($roleName)
{
    return $this->role->name == $roleName;
}
```

to make it work

**EDIT**

You should also probably change your relationship from:

```
public function role()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Role::class);
}
```

into

```
public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
}
```

assuming you have `role_id` column in `users` table

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Then I get Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column roles.user_id does not exist
LINE 1: select * from "roles" where "roles"."user_id" = $1 and "role...
^ (SQL: select * from "roles" where "roles"."user_id" = 1 and "roles"."user_id" is not null limit 1)'. 

That's my problem, I don't know how to write the logic for a one to many table. For many to many it's like this:
`        foreach ($this->role()->get() as $role)
        {
            if ($role->name == $roleName)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;`